# Windows 7: How to show all items that are in control panel?

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

There is a "troubleshooting" menu item in the control panel if you search; how can I display all items that are in the control when viewing it normally (**Note: This has nothing to do with changing the view type to small or large icons**)

Comment: Please delete this; I feel stupid :p

Comment: See this article, does not change Control Panel, but does give a control panel like access to buried Windows features and settings.....http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-10423985-285/understanding-windows-7s-godmode/?tag=pop

Comment: @Moab Wow, that is COOL!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Right-click on the desktop and go to New > Folder to create a new folder.
> 2. Name the folder: GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C} (Complete with the period after GodMode and the curly brackets)
>
>    - Note that you can replace "GodMode" with any text you want, such as "JediMode" or "NinjaMode".
> 3. Open the GodMode folder to access over 260 commands, from administrative tools to backup tools to internet options and other
>      important settings.
>
> You can also drag and drop any of the commands from your GodMode
>   folder to your desktop for quick access in the future.

https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/god-mode-windows-10

---

*Note: just to avoid confusion, the cited link is for Windows 10 and this question from 2011 is tagged Windows 7.  If you are still using a pre-10 version of Windows, this solution does apply.  See https://www.cnet.com/how-to/understanding-windows-7s-godmode/ as cited by Moab in a comment.*

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to add, using the small icon's does indeed show the 'troubleshooting' menu.

Comment: Yea it does but there is a more 'detailed' way to show. For example if you search for psr.exe in start menu, you can open up the control panel that has a more detailed 'troubleshooting' menu. When you click on that troubleshooting menu from the control panel, you do not have the same options

Comment: What's the more detailed way to show?

Comment: Just do a search for psr.exe and click on the control panel option; notice how psr.exe is included in that more detailed view

Answer (score 0):

To show all the icons all the time, regardless of size, layout, etc., you can **edit the group policy.**

Note that this method requires that you have admin access to your system, so business users may be out of luck.

1. Start Menu > Run > `gpedit.msc`
2. If prompted by UAC, click on Yes
3. In the **Local Group Policy Editor** window, navigate to `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel`
4. Select `Control Panel` in the left panel, then move to the right panel
5. Find and double-click on **Always open All Control Panel Items when opening the Control Panel**
6. Set radio button to `Enabled` and click Apply

The group policy has a ton of handy feature tweaks like this, so it's worth exploring a little bit to find others you might like.